# MySqlConnection.Open() suddenly stopped working

Tags: c#, mysql

So I've been running this code fore a couple of weeks without any issues, I even haven't touched this very part of the code for days. It is part of an UWP application, and I use a separate machine to continuously test it.

So when I tested the application in the morning, the query executed as expected. I left the application running, came back to it later, and suddenly couldn't connect anymore.
I restarted the application, which resulted in the same error.
So I compiled it on my laptop, which also resulted in the same error:

"ExtendedSocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions xxx.xx.xxx.x:3306"

The remote server does allow remote connections, I've tested this using an external client.

So, I'm completely lost now...

```
private static LocalStockManager instance;
    private string M_str_sqlcon;
    private MySqlConnection mysqlcon;

    public LocalStockManager()
    {
        M_str_sqlcon = "server=xxx.xx.xxx.x;user id=user;password=pass;database=db";
        mysqlcon = new MySqlConnection(M_str_sqlcon);
    }

    public static LocalStockManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new LocalStockManager();
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

    public int GetLocalAmountOf(string productTag)
    {
        MySqlCommand mysqlcom = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM...", mysqlcon);
        bool bl = mysqlcon.Ping(); // returns false?
        mysqlcon.Open();
        MySqlDataReader mysqlread = mysqlcom.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        int counter = 0;
        while (mysqlread.Read())
        {
            counter = mysqlread.GetInt32(0);
        }
        mysqlcon.Close();

        return counter;
    }
```

Comment: What have you tries so far? It's an easy way trot message to search for

Comment: Well, I've tried a lot, but just now, I tried using the external IP of my network instead of the local IP, and that worked, so I guess something on the remote machine is blocking my local IP range?

Comment: Do you see a change in behavior if you run as Administrator

Comment: No, only when I use an IP different from my LAN IP, like an external server outside of the LAN, or when I'm at home using a VPN on the store router to get into the network... The remote machine runs on Debian, it does not have a firewall and I disabled the clamav daemon...